# "He will take me on a holiday". Is this idiomatic way of saying it?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

Imagine that your friend is going to go on a holiday and he will take you with him. How can say this idiomatically:

Would it be idiomatic if I say **"He will take me on a holiday?**" just like we could say **"He will take me on a trip."**

Comment: No. The idiomatic version is ***He's taking** me on holiday*. Usually [*without* the article before ***holiday***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taking+her+on+holiday%2Ctaking+her+on+a+holiday&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but that's a stylistic choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - suppose it was Cliff Richard (and the boys of course, esp. Hank)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - or [The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/take-me-on-a-holiday-that-helps-5349195.html)?

Comment: [Ngrams not found: **going on summer holiday.**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+on+holiday%2Cgoing+on+a+holiday%2Cgoing+on+summer+holiday%2Cgoing+on+a+summer+holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Once "summer" is included, we pretty much *need* the article.

Comment: Note that *holiday* is UK; *vacation* is US English. I think it depends on the precise situation: is the holiday organised and booked (present tense), or is this hypothetical (future tense)?

Comment: @StuartF, thanks for the answer, but does the main verb change whether it is booked or not? I think the main verb (take someone on holiday) will not change, only the auxiliary verb will change.

Comment: BTW, "go on holiday," is more often UK English, "go on vacation," American. Odd that the British version uses word derived from "holy day," while the Western concept is more generic -- just vacating, i.e., leaving.